# SLKTextViewController from storyboard with UIScrollView

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview

I'm using [`SLKTextViewController`](https://github.com/slackhq/SlackTextViewController) with a `UIScrollView` (`init(scrollView: UIScrollView)`).

Is it possible to create it from storyboard with the `UIScrollView` setup (instead of `UITableView` or `UICollectionView`)?

Comment: Care to explain why the down vote?

Comment: I'll update the question, but if you don't know what `SLKTextViewController` is, I don't expect you to know the answer.

Comment: Updated. Could you remove the down vote?