# Call method from superclass of super in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

Is it possible to call a superclass's superclass's method?

Something like:

```
class A: UIViewController { ... }
class B: A {
    required init(coder decoder: NSCoder!) {
        // I want this to be the UIViewcontroller's implementation
        super.super.init(coder: decoder)

        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you want to call superclass's superclass's method? I'm smelling a kind of [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) here.

Comment: Well, I like the XY reference =). I'm trying another approach to solve that other question you just commented on. Basically I need to hack a third party class so I can call the `UIViewController` init.

Comment: @mitulmarsonia could you tell me how? (`super.super.init(...)` doesn't compile)

Comment: It's non sense (if class A have just super.init)

Comment: @AlessandroOrnano I don't have access to class A (it's from a third party library)

Comment: What's wrong with A's `init`?

Comment: @kennytm lol, it's a long story, but I basically I'm trying to come up with a hack for this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37154114/slktextviewcontroller-from-storyboard-with-uiscrollview

Comment: You're trying to hack an open-source library in a wrong way (that would violate the OOP principles). You need to to fork the library sources and fine-tune it for your needs. Return your changes to the upstream if that makes sense.

Answer (score 2):

Any descent OOP language will deny you to access inheritance hierarchy any deeper than the immediate superclass or encapsulation principle would be broken. Moreover, you then would have near 100% chances to break the superclass internal logic.

So **no**, this is not possible (at least in any *normal* way).

---

But taking into account [your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37154512/call-method-from-superclass-of-super-in-swift#comment61846823_37154512), I would suggest other solution to your real problem.

> ... basically I'm trying to come up with a hack for this
>   [SLKTextViewController from storyboard with UIScrollView](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37154114/3541063)

`SLKTextViewController` is a class from the open-source library [SlackTextViewController](https://github.com/slackhq/SlackTextViewController) (you know) and to amend its behaviour in a way that is not possible via the public interface of the library you can *fork* the library, amend it according to your needs and possibly *return* some changes to the upstream (make a contribution).